# Check to see if a DOM node is inside an Iframe

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to check to see if a DOM Node is inside an iFrame in my application. Is there anyway to find what window the node resides in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (node.ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement)        
    // We're inside of an <iframe>
```

Explantions to the code:

```
node.ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement
//   ^------------------------------------------ The document of the <iframe>.
//                 ^ --------------------------- The window of the <iframe>
//                             ^---------------- The <iframe>
```